# Avoiding nesting maps when "pivoting" multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, functional-programming, lodash

I have data in the format

```
[
  {
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 770,
      "2017-05-07": 760,
      "2017-05-08": 1250
         ...
    }
  },
  {
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 590,
      "2017-05-07": 210,
      "2017-05-08": 300
         ...
    }
  },
  {
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 890,
      "2017-05-07": 2200,
      "2017-05-08": 1032
         ...
    }
  }
]
```

that in order to use in a google chart I need to change to the format

```
[
  ["2017-05-06", 770, 590, 890, ...],
  ["2017-05-07", 760, 210, 2200, ...],
  ["2017-05-08", 1250, 300, 1032, ...]
]
```

I wrote the following to make the transformation

```
let mapped = _.map(
  chartData.results[0].timeline_map, (timestampVal, timestampKey) => (
  [timestampKey].concat(
    _.map(
      chartData.results, lineData => (
        lineData.timeline_map[timestampKey]
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This works, but I'm thinking that nesting the `map`s is not a good idea because how it will increase the amount of looping by the square off the length of the array being mapped. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result here.

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/nepokojiqo/edit?js,console)

Comment: `["2017-05-06": 770, 590, 890, ...]` this is no valid JS. Either `[["2017-05-06", ...], ["2017-05-07", ...]]` or  `{"2017-05-06": [...], "2017-05-07": [...]}`. Wich one is it?

Comment: @Thomas it's just an ellipsis to indicate there's more dates. The linked JSBIN doesn't have any pseudo elements like that

Comment: I'm not talking about the ellipsis, I'm talking about the `:`

Comment: @Thomas Ah. Oops. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Single dimensional array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a closure over a hash table and assign the values accordingly to the date keys.

```js
var data = [{ timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 770, "2017-05-07": 760, "2017-05-08": 1250 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 590, "2017-05-07": 210, "2017-05-08": 300 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 890, "2017-05-07": 2200, "2017-05-08": 1032 } }],
    grouped = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            Object.keys(o.timeline_map).forEach(function (k) {
                if (!hash[k]) {
                    hash[k] = [k];
                    r.push(hash[k]);
                }
                hash[k].push(o.timeline_map[k]);
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is the right way to go but requires just one step further to give the desired result.

Comment: @Redu, do you know the wanted result? o_O

Comment: I presume it's the data format shown in the second snippet... But it's my sixth beers already so there's that too...

Comment: I deleted my answer cuz fundamentally it was identical to Nina's.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you explain what purpose does the closure serve here?

Comment: @1252748, it keeps the reference to the array with the same date for collecting data.

Comment: Where do `r` and `o` coming from as the arguments of that returned function?

Comment: the parameters are supplied by the reduce method.

Comment: These? `(Object.create(null)), [])`?

Comment: `Object.create(null)` initialize `hash` in the closure. the empty array is the start value of the result array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146011/discussion-between-1252748-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 2):

Merge the objects using `_.mergeWith()`, and then `_.map()` the resulting object to an array of arrays:

```js
const arr = [{
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 770,
      "2017-05-07": 760,
      "2017-05-08": 1250
    }
  },
  {
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 590,
      "2017-05-07": 210,
      "2017-05-08": 300
    }
  },
  {
    "timeline_map": {
      "2017-05-06": 890,
      "2017-05-07": 2200,
      "2017-05-08": 1032
    }
  }
];

const result = _.map(_.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (o1, o2) => {
  if(Array.isArray(o1)) {
    o1.push(o2)
    return o1;
  }
  
  if(_.isNumber(o2)) {
    return [o2];
  }
}).timeline_map, (v, k) => [k, ...v]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for nice clean solution. Just pointing out that spread operator will start giving call stack overflow error after array reaches a certain size.