# Why return a function inside of `array#reduce` instead of just passing a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

A few weeks ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398218/avoiding-nesting-maps-when-pivoting-multidimensional-array) about how to rearrange a data structure and received this solution:

```
var data = [{ timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 770, "2017-05-07": 760, "2017-05-08": 1250 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 590, "2017-05-07": 210, "2017-05-08": 300 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 890, "2017-05-07": 2200, "2017-05-08": 1032 } }],
    grouped = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, o) {
            Object.keys(o.timeline_map).forEach(function (k) {
                if (!hash[k]) {
                    hash[k] = [k];
                    r.push(hash[k]);
                }
                hash[k].push(o.timeline_map[k]);
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

However looking at it again I'm not totally certain how this is working
I've not seen this concept of returning a function within reduce before. Clearly it works so there must be some reason, but I'd like some clarification.

#### How does returning a function within this application of `reduce` "work"?

Answer (score 4):

Basically it is a closure over a hash table with a value of a really empty object.

```
grouped = data.reduce(function (hash) {
    return function (r, o) {
        // ...
    };
}(Object.create(null)), []);
```

It uses an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) for the variable `hash` with a scope inside of the callback.

```
function (hash) {
    return function (r, o) {
        // ...
    };
}(Object.create(null))
```

Comment: Can you explain this with more words and for a stupid person please?

Comment: @1252748 its a immediate invoking function, thats executes immediately and retuns another callback. check my answer if you still have some doubt.

Comment: I just don't understand why it needs to be an IIFE. wouldn't reduce's callback be invoked immediately?

Comment: The whole point is that there is no reason to do that. Instead of explaining these contortions, you should provide a version of your solution which doesn't require them and that normal people can understand.

Comment: @torazaburo, right, maybe no need for it, but i use a self contained approach for a helper variable just for the inner callback of reduce.

Answer (score 3):

This answer, unfortunately, was extremely arcane. It should be:

```
var data = [{ timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 770, "2017-05-07": 760, "2017-05-08": 1250 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 590, "2017-05-07": 210, "2017-05-08": 300 } }, { timeline_map: { "2017-05-06": 890, "2017-05-07": 2200, "2017-05-08": 1032 } }];

function group(data) {
  const hash = {};

  return data.reduce(function(r, o) {
    Object.keys(o.timeline_map).forEach(function (k) {
      if (!hash[k]) {
        hash[k] = [k];
        r.push(hash[k]);
      }
      hash[k].push(o.timeline_map[k]);
    });
    return r;
  }, []);
}
console.log(group(data));
```

The solution as provided involved an ill-advised attempt to avoid allocating the `hash` object by means of a self-invoking function which took it as a parameter.

Comment: +1 for the premise, but why not use `const hash = Object.create(null)` to avoid collisions with properties of `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Arcane is a poor choice of words. Whether you should use a solution or not depends on how internally consistent the solution models and correctly solves the problem.  If you do not understand something then ignorance is your own fault, and you will suffer the penalty for not knowing. It is more of an insult to dumb down than it is to challenge.

Comment: @Arrow I'll stick with "arcane". I'm a pretty experienced JS programmer and even I did a double take when looking at this code.

Answer (score 0):

actually your function `function (hash) {` executes immediately as you are invoking that instead of passing, and that returns a callback, which is passed to `reduce`, and then `reduce` invoked with that callback, simple.

**EDIT**

```
.reduce(function(hash){...}, []) //meant passing the callback
.reduce(function(hash){...}**(Object.create(null))**, []) //meant executing the callback
```

so what if

```
function someFn(hash) {return 10}
.reduce(someFn("abc"))
```

that meant `.reduce` will be called with `10` right? because  `someFn` will invoke first and it will return `10`. so similarly what if `someFn` return a callback? `reduce` will be invoked with that callback as an argument. so the case is same here for your case, just the different is the function `someFn` is not created earlier, its created and invoked immediately. (If you don't know the concept of Immediate Invoke function)

Comment: "Simple" is relative.

Comment: yup, that's why added the later version to explain from a grass root.